# How to change a value of an item from another class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm sorry, I just start using Unity 3D, I have no experience with it.
I want to add 500 coins whenever the user win in a level,
in my code, when the user win, a pop up show up, but I want also add 500 coins to the user.
This is my code:

```
public class GameScreen : BaseScreen
{
.....
    public void OpenWinPopup()
    {

        OpenPopup<WinPopup>("Popups/WinPopup", popup =>
        {

            var gameState = GameLogic.GameState;
            var levelStars = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level_stars_" + levelInfo.Number);
            if (gameState.Score >= levelInfo.Star3Score)
            {
                popup.SetStars(3);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level_stars_" + levelInfo.Number, 3);
            }
            else if (gameState.Score >= levelInfo.Star2Score)
            {
                popup.SetStars(2);
                if (levelStars < 3)
                {
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level_stars_" + levelInfo.Number, 2);
                }
            }
            else if (gameState.Score >= levelInfo.Star3Score)
            {
                popup.SetStars(1);
                if (levelStars < 2)
                {
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level_stars_" + levelInfo.Number, 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                popup.SetStars(0);
            }

            var levelScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level_score_" + levelInfo.Number);
            if (levelScore < gameState.Score)
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level_score_" + levelInfo.Number, gameState.Score);
            }

            popup.SetScore(gameState.Score);
            popup.SetGoals(levelInfo.Goals, gameState, LevelGoalsWidget);
        });
    }
}
```

This is the class of `CoinSystem`:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "CoinsSystem", menuName = "MyFirstGame/Systems/Coins system", order = 1)]
public class CoinsSystem : ScriptableObject
{
    private Action<int> onCoinsUpdated;

    public void BuyCoins(int amount)
    {
        var numCoins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("num_coins");
        numCoins += amount;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("num_coins", numCoins);
        onCoinsUpdated?.Invoke(numCoins);
    }

    public void SpendCoins(int amount)
    {
        var numCoins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("num_coins");
        numCoins -= amount;
        if (numCoins < 0)
            numCoins = 0;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("num_coins", numCoins);
        onCoinsUpdated?.Invoke(numCoins);
    }

    public void Subscribe(Action<int> callback)
    {
        onCoinsUpdated += callback;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(Action<int> callback)
    {
        if (onCoinsUpdated != null)
            onCoinsUpdated -= callback;
    }
}
```

I spend I lot of time with no result, it's my first time using Unity 3D.

Comment: `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level_stars_" + levelInfo.Number, 2);` Please don't use PlayerPrefs for things that are not user choice options. If you want to save game state, you should serialize properly to your own file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `GameScreen` class is derived from `MonoBehaviour` I suggest adding a public variable pointing to your `CoinSystem`. Example add this to `GameScreen.cs`:

```cs
public class GameScreen : BaseScreen
{
    // Add this ↓↓
    public CoinsSystem coinsSystem;
}
```

Then drag'n'drop your `CoinsSystem` asset from "Project" tab to your `GameScreen` component property that will be named "Coins System".

After that you can access your `CoinsSystem` via the `coinsSystem` variable, as such:

```cs
public class GameScreen : BaseScreen
{
    public CoinsSystem coinsSystem;

    public void OpenWinPopup()
    {
        coinsSystem.BuyCoins(500);

        OpenPopup<WinPopup>("Popups/WinPopup", popup =>
        {
            // *Rest of OpenPopup<WinPopup> code*
        });
    }
}
```

---

It is however bad habit referring to the serialized value on each value get/set. Recommended usage is via a variable and then have a dedicated `Save()` and `Load()` function. Partial example:

```cs
public class CoinsSystem : ScriptableObject
{
    private Action<int> onCoinsUpdated;

    public int coins;

    public void BuyCoins(int amount)
    {
        coins += amount;
        onCoinsUpdated?.Invoke(coins);

        // Optionally have this to save on each BuyCoins call:
        // Save()
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("num_coins", coins);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("num_coins");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,  but GameScreen class isn't derived from MonoBehaviour..so, what I have to do?

Comment: Thank you so much,  but CoinsSystem class isn't derived from MonoBehaviour..when I try to drag and drop the coinSystem class to GameScreen components,I get this error: (can't add script behaviour CoinSystem, the script needs to derive from MonoBehaviour) ..so, what I have to do?

Comment: I just changed this from : 
public class CoinsSystem : ScriptableObject

to :
public class CoinsSystem : MonoBehaviour

And it's works perfect .. I don't know how to thank you.. you made my day .. Thank you soooo much

Comment: @Dev Glad you got it sorted out!